# Is there a JSON xtype available for dialog fields in AEM (Classic UI)?

Tags: extjs, aem

I have a Classic UI dialog that consists of a multifield & inside that multifield, I want to create a field that produces a JSON object. If such an xtype does exist, then submitting the field should result in the JCR structure (or CRXDE) saving the data as a JSON object like so: `{ "base": "...", "hover": "..." }`.

**What I have attempted:**

- Created a nested multifield (i.e. a multifield inside a multifield). However, filling this nested multifield always results in an array of objects/entries, unlike a non-nested multifield, where if you create one multifield item, the result is one (string) object. I also included a String type hint for this.